# Overflowing text and no scrollbars on multiple select with Bootstrap 4 and Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Mystery one here, I see overflowing text and no scrollbars on multiple select using Bootstrap 4. It's not even an issue with my code, or I'd think I need a moderniser or normaliser script - it happens on [Bootstrap's own example](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/). Looks like this on Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit), Windows 8.1.

[image: this]

Any clues?

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/20604

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 is only in Alpha at the minute. You should report the bugs if you find them.

Try using bootstrap 3 for now and switching to 4 when it is production ready.

FYI it is this property which is causing the issue:

```
button, input, select {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Try adding this to your CSS file and it should be ok then:

```
input {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: ta, I am following a training course for Bootstrap 4, but yes, I would expect bugs in an an Alpha! Thanks for the fix, and I will make a moment to report it ( I found another today elsewhere..)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the behaviour I wanted (scrollbar(s) only when needed) was achieved by

```
select {
    overflow: auto;
}
```